# iTerm2 Bash/Prompt colors faded/different from terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, colors, prompt, iterm

I'm so confused and I've been pulling my hair out for hours now. I've been trying to get my bash text to have the same color as I do on my desktop, it works fine in the default terminal app on mac, although on iTerm2 (which is what I used), the colors are faded and gross.

I've checked my $TERM variable and it's set to 'xterm-256color' as well as my report terminal type in preferences on iterm.

Here is a comparison for reference, the top is iterm and the bottom is terminal (both using the same PS1=blahblah)

[image: Screenshot of my issue]

If anyone has ANY ideas please, please, help me. I'm going to go bald trying to fix this. I'm so frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't related to the shell or any environment variables, it's Terminal's and iTerm's profile settings.

Open up iTerm's preferences via the menu bar or with <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd>, then:

1. Click on the Profiles tab.
2. Click on the Colors section.
3. Set the ANSI Colors manually by clicking on the color boxes and picking a color, or select from the presets.

[image: iterm preferences window]